AutoGen GroupChat error code (openai.BadRequestError: Error code: 400)
I'm pretty new to using AutoGen so I don't know for sure if this is a simple problem to fix but I created two simple agents with the user_proxy to communicate with each other through the "GroupChat" function. However, after the first response from the first agent, it leads to an error code 400 from openai. The following below is the exact error code and I don't really know what the issue is.
openai.BadRequestError: Error code: 400 - {'error': {'message': "Invalid 'messages[2].name': string does not match pattern. Expected a string that matches the pattern '^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$'.", 'type': 'invalid_request_error', 'param': 'messages[2].name', 'code': 'invalid_value'}}
I've been following the tutorials on the AutoGen Github repo and I don't think I've seen anyone really run into this problem.
At first I thought it was just an issue between using different LLMs so I decided to keep it to one LLM (GPT-4) and the issue is still recurring. Any insight?

I had the same error and the problem was that I had named one of my agents using a name with a space. By removing the space, the error disappeared.

God bless you Giorgio ! I spent several hours fixing this and your solution worked !

Really helpful. Thanks Giorgio.

The error you're encountering is due to the fact that agent names can only contain alphanumeric characters, underscores (_), or hyphens (-). Spaces are not allowed in agent names, which is why the name is causing this issue. Remove the spaces from agent name and it will work.
